Plot an arbitrary table of values
I'd like to plot some values over time. Here's a simple pine script as an example:
//@version=5
indicator("test plot values with dates")

items() =>
       time >= timestamp("2024-08-30") ? 0.2 : 
       time >= timestamp("2024-07-26") ? 0.2 : 
       time >= timestamp("2024-06-28") ? 0.1 : 
       time >= timestamp("2024-05-31") ? 0.2 : 
       time >= timestamp("2024-04-26") ? 0.3 : 
       na
plot(items())

Here's the resulting indicator:

Question
Is this the recommended approach? Is there a more idiomatic way to approach this?

Looks good. What exactly is your purpose?

@vitruvius I was just wondering if this is the recommended approach.

I would say so.
